# Uploading file to Spring REST server using Python Requests

Tags: python, spring, scala, rest, python-requests

I am trying to upload a file using python requests to my java/scala spring rest server. I am getting the following response:

```
{"timestamp":1454331913056,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException","message":"Required MultipartFile parameter 'image' is not present","path":"/parking_api/images"}
```

my server code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = Array("/parking_api/images"), method = Array(RequestMethod.POST)) def images(@RequestParam("image") image: MultipartFile) = {
  if (image.isEmpty){
    // handle empty
    new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST
  } else {
    // process
    new ResponseEntity(response, HttpStatus.OK)
  }
}
```

My client code:

```
requests.post(parking_webservice_address, files={"image": ("image", open(event.pathname, "rb"), "image/jpeg")})
```

**I have tried:**

- setting `files` parameter in python code to just `{"image":open(...)}` instead of tuple
- passing image data loaded to memory using `open(...).read()` to `files` parameter in python code
- setting `CommonsMultipartResolver` in server like this

  `@Bean(name="multipartResolver")
  public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver(){
      return new CommonsMultipartResolver();
  }`
- setting multipart headers manually, but then it server expects boundary which is missing as things get from bad to worse

None of these options have worked for me. What am I missing?

Comment: It looks like you need to set the method to Multipart/file-data, http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_enctype.asp. Check the docs of the python lib you are using.

Comment: python-requests does exactly this: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file